# Eclipse has exported the keystore file but not the .apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, keystore

I have completed my app which runs perfectly and am now trying to export it using File => Export. When I do the keystore file gets created but the apk file does not. Eclipse get hung up after hitting the Finish button continuously pending (cursor shows loading icon). This last for up to 40 minutes when I decided to cancel and start again.

When I move the cursor around eclipse afterward the cursor still shows loading in certain panels, like package viewer and task. When I close eclipse and restart it I get the infamous "Workspace in use and cannot be create..." prompt. I, then, go to the meta folder and try to delete the .lock file to no avail, not even the program unlocker works. Task manager also cannot end the task (the CPU usage shows 0% but the memory shows a value and eclipse remains present in task manager).

The only thing I find that allows me to enter eclipse is to reboot my Windows 8.1 pc. Afterward, the same issue repeats itself. Any idea on what gives?

Answer (score 0):

when you get to save file (destation APK file) click browers and you have to type .apk after it.  eg filename.apk.